# Why while running the program I am getting object not callable

Tags: python

```
class College():
    
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        
    def name(self):
        print(self.name)
        
a = College("IIT")
a.name()
```

Comment: Add error message.

Comment: I want it to show the name passed in the class name for eg in my code it shoud print IIT when name is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this because when you are calling the `name()` method but the program (python compiler) thinks that you are calling the name attribute of that object.

To prevent that from happening this just use a different name for every methods, attributes and variables.

```
class College():

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def show_name(self):
        print(self.name)

a = College("IIT")
a.show_name()
```

Comment: Thank you for help I almost forget this that same name of variable and function can cause error in the program

Comment: yea no problem buddy

Answer (score 2):

You gave `a` an instance attribute named `name` when you called `College.__init__`. That shadows the class attribute (i.e., the method) with the same name. Choose a different method or attribute name.

`a.name` is the string `"IIT"`, which is not callable. You can cheat a bit to get access to the method

```
>>> College.name(a)
IIT
```

but it will be cleaner to use separate names for the two attributes.